# How to add spacing between characters in text using VIPS?

Tags: c, vips

I'm using the [VIPS library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIPS_(software)) for manipulating images and adding text to them. I want to know how to add spacing to characters in text?

The following image is an example of what I'm talking about.

[image: Tracking and kerning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pango markup](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Markup.html). For example:

```
vips text x.png '<span letter_spacing="10000">Hello!</span>' --dpi 300
```

To make:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, but for the sake of clarification: does VIPS support all of the pango features listed in that link?

Comment: Hello, yes it does, except for colour output.